# Python for loop expected data structure format

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I have this code in a function that is passing in the variable files, but I cannot figure out what format the list/dictionary should be in.

All my attempts are either giving me 
Value error: too many values to unpack or something simialr whenever I change it.
I have tried fils as :

{'a':'filname'}

['filename']

'filename'

```
if files:
        for key, filename, value in files:
            content_type = self._get_content_type(filename)
            body.write('--%s%s' % (FILE_BOUNDARY, CRLF))
            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data;' + \
                ' name="%s"; filename="%s"%s' % (key, filename, CRLF))
            body.write('Content-Type: %s%s' % (content_type, CRLF))
            body.write(CRLF)
            body.write(value)
            body.write(CRLF)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are three names on the left side, you need to pass it an iterable of 3-element sequences.

```
[
  ('key1', 'filename1', 'value1'),
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

files should be a list of tuples

i.e.

```
files = [
         (key1,filename1,value1),
         (key2,filename2,value2),
         ....
         ]
```

The python command for Y in X means for each item in the sequence X, Y = X[n]

when Y is Y1, Y2, Y3 this means you have Y1, Y2, Y3 = X[n] python would then try to unpack X[n] to 3 values using tuple unpacking.